# My Windows 7 PC can find my Mac but can't connect to it. No password prompt?

Tags: mac, network, windows, file-sharing

I'm trying to access my Mac's files via my Win 7 PC and I'm so close but yet so far. The PC finds the Mac (it is there under 'Network'), but then I can't connect. According to many guides that I've read, there should be some kind of prompt asking me to provide credentials in order to connect, but nothing comes up. Then after a while of waiting I just get this screen...
[image]

I have firewall turned off for both sides, they are both on WORKGROUP. I don't have any other ideas left :/

Comment: First on the Mac, System prefs > Sharing > Options... Do you have SMB on, & the appropriate account enabled?

Comment: Hello, yes, Share files with SMB is on, I have added an account with Sharing Only, as well as my admin account.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely just authentication issues.

On the PC RIGHT-Click on the computer icon and select Map Drive. Enter the path name (I'd use IP address but hostname might work) like this:

```
\\192.168.x.x\[SHORTUSERNAME]
```

*Use the Mac's IP address, then a backslash and then the short username of the account you want to connect to.*

There should be a checkbox for "log on with different credentials." check that

You'll click done (or OK, I don't remember exactly) and the PC will prompt you for a username and a password. Try the username and password of the Mac. If that fails try the fully qualified username, which includes the hostname (computer name) of the Mac, a back slash ( \ ) and then the username on the Mac, followed by the password. That *usually* works for me.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not at home right now but I'll try that and let you know what happens. In the 'if that fails' part, would the password be separated from the username by another slash?

Comment: No, when you map a network drive and have it use different credentials you have two fields, username and password. the username *may* take the form of "domain\username" but the password is *just* the password.

Comment: Ahh OK I understand. Well, unfortunately I can't even see the Mac any more, it's 'disappeared'.

Comment: as long as you have the IP address and it is pingable, and file sharing is on it should work.